# linking new user profiles with existing company profiles on Android device?

Tags: android, mobile

I'll try to be as clear as possible out here. 
I'm working on an android application which is more like a phone directory where I have a big database and I want the new users to claim their company profile which is already registered in our database.
The new users should get the privilege to edit information like phone number, email id and address on their company profile once I manually approve them on the server side.

You can check the attached image for better understanding.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDq3A.jpg)

> When a user clicks on the claim profile button then I should get a notification  on my server that a registered user has requested to claim that specific profile and I need to verify it. The user should be edit the details on the profile page once I verify it.

Can something like this be achieved on an Android device?

Comment: Yes.  Do you have any other questions about it, or just that one?

Comment: @nasch That's the only question I have. I want to know how can I implement it

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to do:

1. Prepare an web service on the server side to check user privilege and notify you.
2. Design an ImageButton and implement OnClickListener to call the web service.
   Reference: http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/
3. Change the icon of ImageButton to "refresh" while the result of web service is waiting for your approving.
4. If the result of web service is approved, set the EditText enabled, change the icon of ImageButton to "save".
5. And so on.